# Why does LuaJIT bytecode put the opcode at the end instead of the front?

Tags: bytecode, interpreter, luajit, vm-implementation

I've been reading up on virtual machines for interpreted languages. Usually the bytecode format is something like `Opcode : Operand/s` but with LuaJIT it's the reverse:

http://wiki.luajit.org/Bytecode-2.0

> A single bytecode instruction is 32 bit wide and has an 8 bit opcode field and several operand fields of 8 or 16 bit. Instructions come in one of two formats:
>
> ```
> B | C | A | OP  
>   D   | A | OP
> ```

Where OP is the opcode and A,B,C,D are operands

My question: Why is LuaJIT different here? Is there some benefit to this order (byte alignment maybe?) or is it an arbitrary design choice?

Comment: My educated guess: you can easily load a 32 bit quantity into a register, followed by using the lowest 8 bits of the register, to perform the right action. Most CPUs have such instructions, whereas using the higher bits without shifting, is less trivial. Real CPU instruction sets are not dependent on the existence of such instructions, as the decoder is hard-coded. And variable sized instruction sets need the opcode at the beginning of a byte sequence, to allow determining the size. But for a fixed 32 bit interpreted instruction set, using the lowest bits seems to be a natural choice.

Comment: Plain Lua also has the opcode in lower bits except its 6 bit http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf